# Js foreach with key=>value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (json['error']) 
{            
    for(var arg in json['error']) {
        $("#e-"+key).html(value);
    }
}
```

I have an array $json['error']
I need to get key and edit  by jquery using value of this array.
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @AkhilAravind I think the attempt is the code block in OP's question.

Comment: @Seblor the block is  nothing, did you see that

Comment: @AkhilAravind I agree the question needs heavy editing.

Comment: i dont use js... so i dont know how to use for... how i can get key from array?

Comment: "*don't know how to use for*" - did you try looking it up?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: For getting keys of an object in JavaScript try using Object.keys(<ObjectName>) method.

Comment: but how i can use it in foreach, like in php: foreach ($val $key=>$value)

Comment: maybe i need for each?

Comment: Voted: close as simple typo given OPs own answer where they used the actual variable name they had rather than some random other variable that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. it's just a problem of knowing js)

```
var err = json['error'];
for(var arg in err) {
    $("#e-"+arg).html(err[arg]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you `for in` loop like this:

```
 for(var arg in json['error']) {
        //arg is the prop
        // json['error'][arg] is the value
        $("#e-"+arg).html(json['error'][arg]);
    }
```

( `json['error']` should be a JS object )